# Using, in a aws LAMBDA, parameters of axios

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I use reactjs to create a web page, and I need to use `GET` from axios to send some parameters to my lambda.

For that i'm using this code:

```
await axios.get("endpoint-API",
  { params: {
resultat_net_N1:`${resultat_net_N1_form}, ${resultat_net_N1}, ${resultat_net_N1_form_1}, ${resultat_net_N1_1}`,
resultat_net_N: `${resultat_net_N_form}, ${resultat_net_N}, ${resultat_net_N_form_1}, ${resultat_net_N_1}`,
              }
         }
    )
```

And my lambda is :

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event.queryStringParameters)
    //or
    // console.log(event.pathParameters )
    const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from new Lambda!'),
   };
};
```

But when i'm trying to use this codes, my lambda is printing all the time `undefined`.
Which brings me to my question, are there a few things I do wrong in my way of sending these parameters with get? or on the lambda aws?
I also used the following method, and I had the same problem:

```
axios.get('my_endpoint/?foo=bar')
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should return the `response`.

Comment: Are you using API Gateway with a Lambda proxy integration? You Lambda code is expecting this, but it's not specified in your questions and therefore may be your problem. Also, first step in debugging Lambdas is to check that the event is structured like you think it is structured, so console.log the whole event and have a look at what is where `console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));`.

Comment: @KMo Sorry, yes i'm using API Gateway wit AWS lambda. When i'm trying to print your console.log, i have just "{}". And it's not really helping me haha

Comment: @dashmug the return is not changing anything but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that you are using a HTTP API Gateway integration with no mapping. This is why your event object is empty.

You should have a look at the different types of API Gateway integration [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html) and decide which is the best fit for you.

But with your current Lambda code, you just need to tick the HTTP Proxy integration box in Integration Request on API Gateway console to get this to work.

Comment: Well, I don’t know how to do it, but now I know the problem is with my API